# how to build a relation between two separate select tag?

Tags: html, html-select

I have two separate `<select>` tags in html form, one select tag contains districts as options, and the other select tag contains number of schools as options, now question is when I select a particular district in the first `<select>` tag,only those schools of that district should be displayed when I click on the second `<select>` tag.

Comment: Please show as what you tried until now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript / JQuery to catch the `Change` event of the first select and manually update the second select.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Alternatively - you could use a binding framework such as `Knockout` or `Angular`.